# How to select element in JavaScript with queryselector which are added later in the code using innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselector

In the following example I have a parent element in my HTML code, and I am embedding the span element with class 'child' inside the parent element using createChild function. Later in the code I am changing content of the child element.

I knew that this will not work because `querySelector` ran before the child element was even created and a simple solution would be selecting the child element after it's been created (i.e selecting the child element with querySelector after the createChild function). But I need some other solution for this problem as I like to select my DOM elements in the beginning of my code and don't want to use querySelectors between my code.

I would really appreciate a simple and effective solution for this problem as I face this issue very often.

**Html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>example code</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Selecting DOM Element
const parentEl = document.querySelector(".parent");
console.log(parent);
const childEl = document.querySelector(".child");

//Functionality
const createChild = function(){
const innerHtml = `<span class = 'child'> Child Element </span>`;
parentEl.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", innerHtml);
}
createChild();

childEl.textContent = "change content"; //Not Working
```

I move the line which is selecting the child element after the function, and it work but I really want my querySelectors at the top of my code so it's more organized and not everywhere in my code. So, I am looking for more ways of achieving the same result.

```
// Selecting DOM Element
const parentEl = document.querySelector(".parent");
console.log(parent);

//Functionality
const createChild = function () {
const innerHtml = `<span class = 'child'> Child Element </span>`;
parentEl.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", innerHtml);
};
createChild();

const childEl = document.querySelector(".child");
childEl.textContent = "change content"; // Working
```

Comment: Your script tag is outside the body.

Comment: You simply cannot select an element which does not exist. You could create a live `HTMLCollection` using `getElementsByClassName` and checking that collection, but it would be a waste of compute power. Ditto with a `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Well using getElementsbyClassName did solve the issue but i did not get what you meant by "it would be a waste of compute power" ?
Seems like you are saying that i should use getElementsbyClassName and also saying that its bad practice.
Sorry if i look like a newbie, i am new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to create the span element with a `createElement` function, instead of using HTML. Then you get the element as return value:

```
const createChild = function(){
    const span = document.createElement('span'); 
    span.classList.add('child');
    span.textContent = 'Child Element';
    return parentEl.appendChild(span);
}
const childEl = createChild();
```

This looks quite logical to me: the function returns what it has inserted into the document.